# Kendo Charts : How to create a Heat Map?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, charts, kendo-ui, heat

Is there a way to create a Heat Map like FusionCharts, but with Kendo UI ?

Here is what I need : http://www.fusioncharts.com/charts/heat-map-charts/

I didn't find a way yet, and it seems that the Kendo team is still on the subjetct (since 2011). But if you found a solution, I'm interested !

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but it's a workaround.

- I used the TreeMap chart, putting every rows value to 1 so they get all the same size.
- I used the kendoTooltip() method to add a tooltip to every rows
- I used the Chroma library to handle the colors, using it in the DataBound function.

The problem is that it can't be exported to PDF.